# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException ? Please help I don't know what to do

Tags: java, pointers, exception, null

this is my code an di get this error, I don't understand why, I tried multiple times to figure it out what is happening, are you able please to help me. I tried to check the several topic that are around here regarding this but nothing similar found and if I need to do a null check, I am new to this and I don't understand exactly what I need to do

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;






import java.sql.*;






public class JavaCrud {
    
private JPanel Main;
   
 private JTextField txtName;

    private JButton saveButton;

    private JButton deleteButton;

    private JButton updateButton;

    private JTextField textField2;

    private JTextField txtPrice;

    private JTextField txtQty;



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JavaCrud");
        frame.setContentPane(new JavaCrud().Main);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JavaCrud() {

        Connect();

        saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String name, price, qty;

                name = txtName.getText();
                price = txtPrice.getText();
                qty = txtQty.getText();

                try {
                    pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into products(pname,price,qty)values(?,?,?)");
                    pst.setString(1, name);
                    pst.setString(2, price);
                    pst.setString(3, qty);
                    pst.executeUpdate();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Record Addedddddd!!!!");

                    txtName.setText("");
                    txtPrice.setText("");
                    txtQty.setText("");
                    txtName.requestFocus();
                }

                catch (SQLException e1)
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        deleteButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String bid;

                bid = textField2.getText();


                try {
                    pst = con.prepareStatement("delete from products  where pid = ?");
                    pst.setString(1, bid);

                    pst.executeUpdate();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Deleteeeeee!!!!!");

                    txtName.setText("");
                    txtPrice.setText("");
                    txtQty.setText("");
                    txtName.requestFocus();
                    textField2.setText("");
                }

                catch (SQLException e1)
                {

                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        updateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String pid,name,price,qty;

                name = txtName.getText();
                price = txtPrice.getText();
                qty = txtQty.getText();
                pid = textField2.getText();

                try {

                    pst = con.prepareStatement("update products set pname = ?,price = ?,qty = ? where pid = ?");
                    pst.setString(1, name);
                    pst.setString(2, price);
                    pst.setString(3, qty);
                    pst.setString(4, pid);

                    pst.executeUpdate();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Updateee!!!!!");

                    txtName.setText("");
                    txtPrice.setText("");
                    txtQty.setText("");
                    txtName.requestFocus();
                    textField2.setText("");
                }

                catch (SQLException e1)
                {

                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    public void Connect(){
        try{
            Connection con;
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gbproducts","root","root");
            System.out.println("Success");
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

A NullPointerException is thrown because you adding an `addActionListener` to your button that has not been instantiated.

In your `JavaCrud()` method you need to instantiate your buttons.

```
saveButton = new JButton("SAVE"); 
deleteButton = new JButton("DELETE"); 
updateButton = new JButton("UPDATE");
```

You would also need to instantiate your `JTextfield` because after a user clicks on a button you are trying to `getText()` from a JTextField that is null.

Also, it is better to `implements ActionListener` to your class than to addActionListener to every button. It allows for cleaner code and easier debugging.

Here you can read up on [ActionListener Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)